# How to check Outlook folder has mail or not

Tags: azure-logic-apps, office365connectors

What Azure service allows us to run at a fixed interval (IE every 5 min), and if a given Outlook/mailbox folder has one or more emails in it, then send one notification email?

We have a Logic App that does email processing. If the processing fails for whatever reason, the email is placed into a "Failed" folder, and an email notification is sent out.  The issue is when a dependent service is down, we are getting hundreds of email an hour.

We tried creating a second Logic App that runs every 5 min, sending email if it found email in the folder that is "flagged", but we still received one email per flagged email.

We are thinking a separate service that runs every so often, and if a folder has email in it, then send out a single email.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a Outlook trigger action to detect if there is an email is flagged. It supports to change the Folder,Importance,Interval and add other parameters to match.

[image]

And this is the action [Optional Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/office365connector/#when-an-email-is-flagged) description.

Comment: That is what we did in our second logic app, but as I mentioned, we still got an email for every email flagged.